# How to restore the rhandsontable package's disabled 'Undo' from the context menu in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rscript, rhandsontable

For one of my Rshiny app, I am referring to this R shiny code from StackOverflow:
[In R Shiny, how do you reset data (reversing all manual inputs) in rhandsontable using an actionButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68496116/in-r-shiny-how-do-you-reset-data-reversing-all-manual-inputs-in-rhandsontable)

When we use the package "rhandsontable," the following code displays the DataTable whenever we click the "show" button. Although the rhandsontable package includes a default context menu, it can be customized using the "hot_context_menu" code.

**issue**:

The problem is with the 'undo' option in the context menu (right-click on the data table). The option 'undo' enabled to work only when we adjust alignment (right-click on the data table), but not (disabled) when we remove a row (Remove row), "insert row below," and so on.

Could someone help me to fix this issue?

**original code**

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(actionButton("show", "Show"),
                actionButton("reset", "Reset"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dat <- reactiveVal(data.frame(x = runif(5), y = runif(5)))
  
  observeEvent(input$hot, {
    dat(as.data.frame(hot_to_r(input$hot)))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$show, {
    showModal(modalDialog(rHandsontableOutput("hot")))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    dat(data.frame(x = runif(5), y = runif(5)))
  })
  
  output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
    # input$show
    rhandsontable(dat())
  })
  
} # close Server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Edited Code**

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(actionButton("show", "Show"),
                actionButton("reset", "Reset"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dat <- reactiveVal(data.frame(x = runif(5), y = runif(5)))
  
  observeEvent(input$hot, {
    dat(as.data.frame(hot_to_r(input$hot)))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$show, {
    showModal(modalDialog(rHandsontableOutput("hot")))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    dat(data.frame(x = runif(5), y = runif(5)))
  })
  
  output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(dat())
  })
  outputOptions(output, "hot", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE) 
  
} # close Server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This seems to be an [issue](https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable/issues/375) with the shiny implementation - it's working fine when used without shiny: `rhandsontable(data.frame(x = runif(5), y = runif(5)))`.

Comment: Are you interested in a workaround so, that the reset button is able to remove added rows?

Comment: @ismirsehregal, Yes, that will much assist me in resolving this problem. Please assist me in finding a workaround.

Comment: Just set `outputOptions(output, "hot", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)` after assigning the `rhandsontable` to `output$hot`, to make the reset button work regarding additional / removed rows. By default re-rendering isn't triggered for hidden outputs.

Comment: @ismirsehregal, I have tried this functionality several times and it still doesn't work. In my original post, under "Edited Code," I included the updated(edited) code. Could you assist me with this?

Comment: With the "edited code" the table is back to 5 rows after pressing reset (if the table was modified).

Comment: @ismirsehregal, Thank you very much. However, I am looking for a solution that uses the UNDO option in the context menu rather than the reset option. Could you help me with that?

Comment: @ismirsehregal, Could you help me on this?

Comment: As the issue I linked above suggests, I think this is either a implementation limitation or a bug and hopefully the package maintainer will look into it. I don't have a workaround for this.